# access files in WEB-INF/lib from WAR in Wildfly

Tags: web, singleton, startup, wildfly, vfs

I´m trying to deploy an Java EE aplication on WildFly, this application contains a EJB which do a task with applications jars, this jars files stay in WEB-INF/lib inside the .war file, bellow is a stretch of code.

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class ORMClassFinder {

/**
 * Path para inicio da leitura de todos os jars do projeto.
 */
private static final String PATH_BASE = "/WEB-INF/lib/";


/**
 * Metodo que inicia a busca listando todos os jars do projeto. Ele é executado no start da aplicação.
 */
@PostConstruct
public void listAllJars() {
    String[] tmpPath = this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath().toString()
                    .split( PATH_BASE );
    File file = new File( tmpPath[0] + PATH_BASE );
```

The URI if used by new File() result is:

```
C:/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/bin/content/ciss-erp-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/
```

but, this directory don´t exists in my wildfly file tree, this folder exists in:

```
C:/wildfly-8.2.0.Final/standalone/deployments/ciss-erp-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war/WEB-INF/lib/
```

I don´t understand why the URI with **bin/content** is generated, anyone had this problem sometime?

i think if exists a more correct solution for this, because Wildfly already needs to load all resources for deploy, i search about classload, and Wildfly uses VFS2, maybe it´s possible to use it to find paths and files?

Comment: Hi, what are you trying to do with the file? You should consider getting it as a resource from the class loader.

Comment: This get all ORM classes to map in hibernate, i do it now with **org.jboss.vfs.VFS** class loader for list all jars, but soon will trade the server from _Wilfly_ to _WebSphere_, and now i will try to  implementation like jboss VFS.

Comment: Why not just use servletContext.getRealPath("WEB-INF/lib") which will return you real path to your lib folder.